# There was an error to lookup cluster groups

Tags: sql-server

During installation of another node to fail-over cluster, after select SQL Sever Instance Name in the step *Cluster Node Configuration* and click Next button, installation crashed and not responding, then  raised this error

**There was an error to lookup cluster groups. Error: There was a failure to call cluster code from a provider. Exception message: Critical error . Status code: 4106. Description: Critical error**

I saw installation log file , i found this error:

```
(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:46 Slp: Running Action: RunScenarioGlobalRules

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:46 Slp: Running in UI mode, unattended rules execution skipped.

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:46 Slp: Completed Action: RunScenarioGlobalRules, returned True

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:46 Slp: ----------------------------------------------------------------------

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:46 Slp: Running Action: DiscoverClusterData

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: There was an issue determining the cluster debugging information. Setup will continue.

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Exception type: System.InvalidOperationException

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Message:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: There was an error generating the XML document.

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: HResult : 0x80131509

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Stack:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.ClusterConfiguration.DiscoverClusterDataAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.ClusterGroupsLookupException

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Message:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: There was an error to lookup cluster groups. Error: There was a failure to call cluster code from a provider. Exception message: Critical error . Status code: 4106. Description: Critical error

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: .

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: HResult : 0x86d8000e

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: FacilityCode : 1752 (6d8)

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: ErrorCode : 14 (000e)

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Data:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: errorMessage = There was a failure to call cluster code from a provider. Exception message: Critical error . Status code: 4106. Description: Critical error

.

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.ClusterGroupsLookupException@14

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Stack:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.WindowsCluster.get_Groups()

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write113_WindowsCluster(String n, String ns, WindowsCluster o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write237_WindowsCluster(Object o)

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.ClusterProviderDetailedException

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Message:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: There was a failure to call cluster code from a provider. Exception message: Critical error . Status code: 4106. Description: Critical error

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: .

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: HResult : 0x86d70002

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: FacilityCode : 1751 (6d7)

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: ErrorCode : 2 (0002)

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Data:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: ExceptionMessage = Critical error

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: StatusCode = 4106

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Description = Critical error

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: WatsonData = Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.ClusterProviderDetailedException@2

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Stack:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.WMICollectionWrapper.WmiEnumeratorWrapper.MoveNext()

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.ClusterProvider.<get_Groups>d__11.MoveNext()

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.WindowsCluster.get_Groups()

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Inner exception type: System.Management.ManagementException

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Message:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Critical error

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: HResult : 0x80131501

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Data:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: WmiErrorCode = CriticalError

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: WatsonData = CriticalError@4106

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Description = Critical error

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: ErrorType = 2

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Operation = ExecQuery

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: ParameterInfo = select * from MSCluster_ClusterToResourceGroup where __CLASS = "MSCluster_ClusterToResourceGroup"

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: ProviderName = WinMgmt

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: StatusCode = 4106

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Stack:

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Cluster.WMICollectionWrapper.WmiEnumeratorWrapper.MoveNext()

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Completed Action: DiscoverClusterData, returned True

(01) 2024-02-28 11:19:47 Slp: Completed Action: ExecuteGlobalRulesWorkflow, returned True
```

In the Cluster log file I found this error:

```
mscs::TopologyPersister::TryGetNetworkPrivateProperties: (2)' because of 'OpenSubKey(Parameters) failed.'
```

First of all I thought my Cluster lacks enough permissions but after talking with a Network Administrator, I found the cluster and I have very high permissions.

There is another problem with this issues.

When I run this command in PowerShell

```
get-wmiobject mscluster_resourcegroup  -namespace "ROOT\MSCluster
```

I got this error

[image: Error Critical]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please, **Never** post images of text for the reasons outlined [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). Please edit your post and include the text **AS** text! Use the quote widget above the editing window - you can always edit your own posts!

Comment: Have you run Cluster Validation? Is the latest validation report successful?

Comment: Yeah,I run validation cluster and result is successful and there are not any errors , just some numbers warning likes different version of OS  but compatible

Comment: You're clearly having WMI issues, I'd check to make sure the namespace exists and you have permissions.

Comment: @SeanGallardy  I checked WMI and ResetRepository on all nodes and successfull

Comment: Solve it ,oh my god ,hidden character !!!! ,role name has hidden character just view in DOS Mode and powerShell